# MYSQL display nested results using four LEFT JOINS and LIMIT CLAUSES

Tags: php, mysql, nested, left-join, limit

I have been working with this query trying to get it to output nested results using five tables, but have failed time and time again i think I'm suppose to use sub-queries but I don't understand them enough to put them to use in my code.

I have been really beating my head can some please show me how to get the results I'm looking for.

i need to output 10 of my friends questions with 5 of their respected answers along with 1 category and 8 of the categories tags

The following is what the 10 outputs should look like:

- **Friend:** John Doe 1

  - **Category:** Math
  - **Tags:** tag1 tag2, tag3 ect...
- **Question: what is 1 + 1?**
- math question answer 1
- math question answer 2
- math question answer 3
- math question answer 4
- math question answer 5
- etc...

In order to achieve the above, I'm using the following MYSQL statement and PHP snippet

```
<?php 

$query = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT
        question.post,          
        question.id,     
        question.user_id,

        question_responses.id response_id,
        question_responses.response,

        category.id category_id,
        category.category_name,
        category.category_posts_id cpid,

        tags.tag_name tn,
        tags.id tagid,

        friends.id myid,
        friends.logged_username,

    FROM (SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY question.id DESC LIMIT 10) AS question

    LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.friend_id = question.user_id    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM question_responses LIMIT 5) AS question_responses ON question_responses.question_response_id = question.id
    LEFT JOIN category ON category.user_id = question.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tags LIMIT 8) AS tags ON tags.top_tags = category.category_id

    WHERE friends.user_id = ?");

    $id = "1";

$query->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

try {

    $query->execute();
    $questions = array();
    $question_responses = array();
    $tag = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $question_id = $row['id'];
        $tags_id = $row['tagid'];

        $questions[$question_id] = $row;
        $tags[$tags_id][] = $row;
        $question_responses[$question_id][] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($questions as $question_id => $row) { 
        foreach ($tag as $tags_id => $row) {
            echo $row['tn'];
        }
        echo "<b>".$row['post']."</b></br></br>";
        foreach ($question_responses[$question_id] as $response_id => $row) {    
            echo $row['response']."</br></br>";
        }

    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it's a good idea to put your code & your expected results out, however not everyone will have the patient to read through all your code. Try to point out a specific problem you are having. Maybe showing a sample of what your current output looks like, so people will have a quick image of what you need.

Comment: I don't see much problem in your general structure. If the SQL got all the data you need, then your problem is "i don't know how to format it in php". If somehow you NEED to put the formatting in SQL and could not do it post-query, then it's a SQL problem. Which one is it...?

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to do this using lots of user variables. This is likely to be slow. It has sub queries that bring the results back with a count added, then discards the unwanted ones in the ON clause.

```
SELECT
    question.post,          
    question.id,     
    question.user_id,

    question_responses.id response_id,
    question_responses.response,

    category.category_id,
    category.category_name,
    category.cpid,

    category.tn,
    tagstagid,

    friends.id myid,
    friends.logged_username

FROM  friends
INNER JOIN 
(   
    SELECT category.user_id,
            category.id AS category_id,
            category.category_name,
            category.category_posts_id AS cpid,
            tags.tag_name AS tn,
            tags.id AS tagid,
            @category_user_id_cnt:=IF(@category_user_id = user_id, @category_user_id_cnt + 1, 1) AS category_user_id_cnt,
            @tag_cnt:=IF(@category_user_id = user_id, @tag_cnt + 1, 1) AS tag_cnt,
            @category_user_id := user_id
    FROM category
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @category_user_id=0, @category_user_id_cnt:=0, @tag_cnt:=0) sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags
    ON tags.top_tags = category.category_id
) AS category
ON category.user_id = friends.user_id
AND category.category_user_id_cnt = 1
AND category.tag_cnt <= 8
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post,          
            id,     
            user_id,
            @question_user_id_cnt:=IF(@question_user_id = user_id, @question_user_id_cnt + 1, 1) AS question_user_id_cnt,
            @question_user_id := user_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT post,          
                id,     
                user_id 
        FROM question 
        ORDER BY user_id, id DESC 
    ) sub_question
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @question_user_id=0, @question_user_id_cnt:=0) sub0
) AS question
ON friends.friend_id = question.user_id    
AND question.question_user_id_cnt <= 10
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id response_id, 
            question_responses.response,  
            @question_response_cnt:=IF(@question_response_id = question_response_id, @question_response_cnt + 1, 1) AS question_response_cnt,
            @question_response_id := question_response_id
    FROM question_responses 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @question_response_id=0, @question_response_cnt:=0) sub0
) AS question_responses ON question_responses.question_response_id = question.id AND question_responses.question_response_cnt <= 5

WHERE friends.user_id = ?
```

It might well be possible to do a faster version using tricks with GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX to have sub queries to get the latest X ids and join those back against the tables to get the rest of the data. However doing this I am struggling as I do not know if a friend can only give one answer to a question.